# Email from a spreadsheet with array as message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a script that sends emails each day from a spreadsheet that is changing (filtering itself using the TODAY() function to put new data on a certain sheet for each day). My problem is that I need the message of the email to include an array of about 15 rows and 7 columns from the sheet. This code just wants to grab one cell as the entire message.

Also, this has the functionality to put 'EMAIL_SENT' into a cell to make sure that it doesn't resend it. The problem is for this purpose, I'd like to have it trigger each night and send just one email, and then trigger the next night and send the same email again... The data in the array will have changed.

Thanks for your help!
Alex

```
 var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
var NA = "N/A";

function sendEmails2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById( 'MY ID' ),
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName( 'Daily Reports' ),
      startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2000;   // Number of rows to process

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 6, numRows, 13)

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[10];  // First column
    var message = row[11];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[12];     // Third column
    if ((emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) && ((emailAddress != "#N/A") && (emailAddress != 0))) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = row[0];
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 18).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How many emails do you want to send per night? Is it one per row? or one total?

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple cells in the message of your email by just adding them. Something like

```
var message = "Value1: " + row[10] + "  Value2: " + row[11] ...
```